# Optimizing sql condition to apply condition to all dependent rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query, split up into a view for readability:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW task_depcount AS
SELECT
    t.*,
    COUNT(p.id) AS unfinished_dep_count
FROM
    task t
    LEFT JOIN taskdependency d on t.id = d.task_id
    LEFT JOIN task p on  d.parent_task_id = p.id and p.status != 'SUCCESS'
GROUP BY t.id;

SELECT   t.id, t.task_type, t.status
FROM     task_depcount t
WHERE    t.status = 'READY' AND t.unfinished_dep_count = 0;
```

Now If we're looking at the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output, this is obviously very inefficient, as we cannot really do index scans over a COUNT() result. Rewriting into a single query with `HAVING` would also not improve it.

So here's the question: Is there a way to write this query so that the database isn't forced to do sequence scans all over? Database is PostgreSQL 9.2, with no option to upgrade to newer versions.

Or, to state the intended result in plain english: I need all the tasks where either all it's dependencies are of status "success", or there are no dependencies at all.

Comment: Could you post indexes on your tables too?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas: There are indexes on all fields that I'm searching on, so this should not be the issue. The question really is how to get around filtering the COUNT()ed result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM task t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM taskdependency d JOIN 
                       task p
                       ON d.parent_task_id = p.id 
                  WHERE t.id = d.task_id AND p.status <> 'SUCCESS'
                 );
```

With the right indexes, this should be much faster.

The use of an aggregation function such as `COUNT()` -- whether in a view, subquery, or CTE -- requires processing all the data.  With `NOT EXISTS`, the processing can stop for each at the first unsuccessful one (if any) and not have to do any aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

```
create temporary view task_depcount as
select t.*
from
    task t
    left join
    taskdependency d on t.id = d.task_id
    left join
    task p on d.parent_task_id = p.id
group by t.id
having not bool_or(p.status != success) or not bool_or(d.task_id is not null)
;

select t.id, t.task_type, t.status
from task_depcount t
where t.status = 'READY'
```